# Flattening array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a solution to flatten an array of multiple levels in Javascript. I am just a newbie so forgive any mistakes. Could someone give me any tips to improve the code?

```
function streamrollArray(arr) {
    var copyArr = arr;
    var to_return = [];

    while (true) {
        if (copyArr.length <= 0) { return to_return; }
        var head = copyArr[0];
        to_return = to_return.concat(getValues(head));
        //Chop head off since we have got all the values from it.
        copyArr = copyArr.splice(1);
    }
}

function getValues(arr) {
    var copyArr = arr;
    var to_return = [];

    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        return arr;
    }

    while (true) {
        //A head can contain multiples arrays inside it.
        if (copyArr.length <= 0) { return to_return; }
        var head = copyArr[0];
        to_return = to_return.concat(getHead(head));
        copyArr = copyArr.slice(1);
    }
}

function getHead(head) {
    //If its an array we break into it getting the head and keep checking.
    while (Array.isArray(head)) {
        head = head[0];
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that this might be a problem best solved via recursion.

For example:

```
function flattenArray(arr) {
    var result = [];

    arr.forEach(function($val) {
        if(Array.isArray($val)) {
            result = result.concat(flattenArray($val));
        } else {
            result.push($val);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Also consider a more meaningful name for your function like `flattenArray` vs. `steamrollArray`.  This better conveys what the function does.  Look at your question title for example. You used `Flattening array` to describe your code not `Steamrolling array`.

Comment: sorry streamrollArray is part of freecodecamp algorithms challenges which I am doing. Your right recursion makes the code shorter!

Answer (score -2):

I would consider a slight modification of Mike's code to avoid creating so many intermediate arrays:

```
function flattenArray(arr, outputArray) {
    outputArray ||= [];

    arr.forEach(function($val) {
        if(Array.isArray($val)) {
            flattenArray($val, outputArray));
        } else {
            outputArray.push($val);
        }
    });

    return outputArray;
}
```

Comment: -1 for no explanation at all.